# How to find a particular class object from a List of Object in Spring boot Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am creating a Plugin system, where the plugin will be fetched from DB, my Implementation is like below

A base Plugin Interface

```
@Service
public interface Plugin{
   somemethod();
}
```

In plugin package load all the plugin where inner package name will be plugin name and a class with plugin name

```
package <>.plugin.Myplugin

import ....

@Service 
class MyPlugin implements Plugin {
   @Override
   somemethod() {}
}
```

I am loading all the implemented class of Plugin interface in dependency injection

```
@Controller
public class MyCon {

   private List<Plugin> plugins

   public MyCon(List<Plugin> plugins) {
        this.plugins = plugins;
   }

   ssomefuncitonality() {

        String objectNeedOfClass = <CLASS_NAME>;
        //Here
        System.out.println(this.plugins);
   }
}
```

Here can see all the object in the list, but how can I fetch the perticular object of the provided class Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the list and check the class name:

```
Optional<Plugin> plugin = this.plugins.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(objectNeedOfClass))
        .findFirst();
```

If `plugins` can be large and you do this often, build a map in the constructor:

```
private Map<String, Plugin> plugins

public MyCon(List<Plugin> plugins) {
    this.plugins = plugins.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            p -> p.getClass().getSimpleName(), Function.identity()));
}

ssomefuncitonality() {
    String objectNeedOfClass = ...;
    Plugin plugin = this.plugins.get(objectNeedOfClass);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I don't even check the code but I understand the concept really thank you.